# Stack level too deep upgrading to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-3-upgrade

I'm upgrading an app to Rails 3 and have been going through it bit by bit, for example replacing all the old plugins with the relevant gems in the gemfile.

I seem to have got stuck however because now whenever I try to run the server I get this:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:35: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

I've been googling it for ages and have come to the conclusion that it is still because of one of the plugins, I just can't figure out which one. I have removed each one individually but none of them makes a difference.

I found these three similar questions but they don't really help me....

[Stack level too deep error after running bundle update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391356/stack-level-too-deep-error-after-running-bundle-update)

[SystemStackError at the rack level in Ruby 1.9.2, not 1.8.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055656/systemstackerror-at-the-rack-level-in-ruby-1-9-2-not-1-8-7)

[Stack level too deep trying to update from 3.0 to 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725283/stack-level-too-deep-trying-to-update-from-3-0-to-3-1)

My gemfile looks like this at the moment:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "rails", "3.0.0"

#need to replace old acts_as_commentable vendor plugin
gem 'acts_as_commentable', '3.0.1'
gem "airbrake"
#need to add authlogic gem
gem 'authlogic', '~> 2.1.6'
gem "aws-s3"
gem "bj"
gem "bundler", "~> 1.0.0"
gem "calendar_date_select", "1.15"
gem "cancan", "1.2.0"
gem "carmen"
#replace plugin casein?
gem 'casein', '3.1.0'
gem 'comma', '0.4.1'
gem 'exifr'
# factory_girl 1.2.4 wasn't working with Rails 3 - consider an upgrade to factory_girl_rails?
# gem "factory_girl", "1.2.4"
gem 'fastercsv'
gem "geokit"
#need to replace above with below
gem 'geokit-rails'
gem "haml"
gem "hpricot"
gem 'hoptoad_notifier'
gem "jrails"
gem "libxml-ruby", "2.4.0"
gem "memcached", "~> 1.8.0"
#memcached no longer works?
gem 'dalli'
# Not sure why we have this if we're using SQLite3
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.6"
#TODO: changed by almazom
gem "rake", "0.8.4"
gem 'recurly'
gem "rdoc"
gem "rmagick"
gem "rspreedly"
gem "rubyzip"
gem 'sass'
# searchlogic not supported for rails3
# gem 'searchlogic'
gem 'rd_searchlogic', :require => 'searchlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/railsdog/searchlogic.git'
#need to use simplecov when upgrading to ruby 2 as rcov doesn't work
gem "simplecov"
gem 'sqlite3'
# tmail no longer included in rails 3?
gem 'tmail'
#need to upgrade will_paginate for casein...?
# gem "will_paginate", "2.3.16"
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'yaml_db'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'test-unit', '1.2.3'
  gem 'rspec', '1.3.2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 1.3.4'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '0.3.5'
  gem 'cucumber', '1.1.2'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :git => "git://github.com/RKelln/cucumber-rails.git", :branch => "0.3.2-capybara-fix"
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

And the plugins I have are:

- acts-as-favorite-updated
- acts_as_configurable
- acts_as_follower
- better_logging
- concerned_with
- default_value_for
- fast_context
- fetcher
- has_many_friends
- jrails
- paperclip
- parallel_tests
- rails_upgrade
- yaml_db

Does anyone have any idea how I can deal with this issue?? :-(

Comment: Based on what lib/rack/builder.rb does at line 35, I'd check config.ru

Comment: Won't be causing you the problem, but remove the fastercsv gem, as that comes standard in 1.9+. Use CSV instead of FasterCSV in your code.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I've checked my config.ru file and it looks fine...